# Examples of $\mathbb{Z}_p$-extensions and two $\mathbb{Z}_p$-extensions with a "nontrivial" intersection

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory, iwasawa-theory

Let $k$ be a number field (a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$). Let $p$ be a prime. By saying "*$\mathbb{Z}_p$-extensions*", we mean Galois extensions $K/k$ of Galois group isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

In R. Greenberg's article "*The Iwasawa invariants of $\Gamma$-extensions of a fixed number field*" (1973), he considered the set $\mathcal{E}$ of all $\mathbb{Z}_p$-extensions of $k$.
Moreover, he put a topology on $\mathcal{E}$ by giving a topological basis as follows: Fix any $K \in \mathcal{E}$. For any integer $n \geq 0$, consider
$$
\mathcal{E}(K,n) := \{ K^{\prime} \in \mathcal{E}: [K \cap K^{\prime}: k] \geq p^n \}.
$$
One varies $K$ and $n$ as positive integers to get a topological basis for $\mathcal{E}$.

**My question is**: how to explicitly construct elements in $\mathcal{E}(K,n > 0)$?

**Example**: Let $k = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-d})$ be an imaginary quadratic field. Then it has two "independent" $\mathbb{Z}_p$-extensions, namely the cyclotomic one $k_{\mathrm{cyc}}$ and the other is the anticyclotomic one $k_{\mathrm{ac}}$. We see $k_{\mathrm{cyc}} \cap k_{\mathrm{ac}} = k$, hence
$$
k_{\mathrm{ac}} \in \mathcal{E}(k_{\mathrm{cyc}}, 0), \quad k_{\mathrm{ac}} \not\in \mathcal{E}(k_{\mathrm{cyc}}, n > 0). 
$$
Then in this case my question is that can we construct explicitly $\mathbb{Z}_p$-extensions in the "nontrivial case", i.e. in $\mathcal{E}(k_{\mathrm{cyc}}, n > 0)$? Here by saying "explicit", I mean besides proofs on existence, can we get an explicit construction?

**"Example"**: For general number fields $k$, the only $\mathbb{Z}_p$-extension I know is the cyclotomic one, so I cannot give any further examples. Therefore,

**Another question**: **Besides cyclotomic $\mathbb{Z}_p$-extensions, do we have other explicit examples of $\mathbb{Z}_p$-extensions that we familiar with**? Both systematically constructed examples and ad-hoc examples are welcome!

Since the only "explicit" $\mathbb{Z}_p$-extensions I know is $\mathbb{Q}_{\mathrm{cyc}}$, the above $k_{\mathrm{cyc}}$ and $k_{\mathrm{ac}}$, I have no idea on how to construct elements in $\mathcal{E}(k_{\mathrm{cyc}}, n > 0)$.

I am so sorry if this post is too trivial for this site.

Comment: The composite of $k_{\mathrm{ac}}$ and $k_{\mathrm{cyc}}$ is a $\mathbb{Z}_p^2$-extension, say $K$. Hence if $U$ is any closed subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_p^2$, $K^U$ is an extension of $k$ with Galois group $\mathbb{Z}_p^2 / U$. Playing with this, you can get lots of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ extensions...